# Filling minecarts on command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm performing some experiments with the new track types and have run into a problem — I want to test the physics of occupied carts without being in them myself (as that makes it very hard to see the "big picture").

I have the [Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?t=100267) mod installed, but the `spawn` command doesn't target the way I expected it to.  Instead of creating an NPC where I'm looking (say, at a minecart), the NPC seems to be spawned at a random point near me.

Is there a way to reliably put a rider in a cart with SPC or another mod?

Comment: This may or may not help, but you could also press F5 in-cart to go to third person view, which would give you a different perspective.  Alternatively, spawn a bunch of chickens, and one will undoubtedly jump in.

Comment: Sadly, bulk-spawning doesn't seem to be an ideal approach.  `spawn pig 100` only ended up filling half my carts and was an incredible mess to clean up afterward!  :-D

Comment: @BenBlank: does `butcher` work in SPC?

Comment: what about just getting a zombie or anything to follow you, jump over the minecart and the zombie will get stuck in the minecart.

Comment: @Ksilem — Mobs colliding with minecarts doesn't seem to work; the minecart has to be in motion to pick them up.

Comment: @Tobias — It does, but it kills everything within range, including my poor test pilots.

Answer (score 5):

I know this dodges your answer, but you could run a local server (copying your SSP map to it) after changing the server.properties's online-mode to false, run a second instance of minecraft in *offline mode*, connect both to your local pc and have the offline char sit in the minecart, then alt+tab to the original instance to watch "yourself" ride the cart.

Comment: (AFAIK the only remaining difference between SMP and SSP is the lack of nether unless you use e.g. [nethrar](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/10874) for [bukkit](http://bukkit.org))

Comment: Very clever! Is there a way to deliberately start MC in offline mode, short of disconnecting your internet connection?

Comment: @BenBlank: sure, just delete the last character of your stored password (since that's an invalid login then, it will offer offline mode. This will _not_ delete the stored correct password, i.e. when you start the next time by simply clicking the login button you'll be online again)

Comment: (follow-up on my nether comment, [it's planned](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/5136312534))